# how store dynamic list of sequence numbers in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

In my iOS app, I need to keep track of which sequence numbers have already been received from the server and which sequence numbers need to be retrieved.  I want to be able to store this in case the app terminates or crashes.

I am trying to decide which storage method I should use: core data, plist etc.

The list of sequence numbers is dynamic and can change a lot.  Any pointers on how to decide on storage will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use NSUSerDefaults.. handy and fast... make an array or dictionary and store this in userDefaults

Answer (score 0):

Without more exact details in your question it is hard to give you an accurate answer. However, what can be provided is some insights on the benefits / downfalls of using the storage systems listed above.

I would stay away from using a plist since your data is dynamic and can change a lot. Every time you save to a plist you will need to overwrite the entire file. This means to change a single value you must retrieve all values, make a single change, and save all values back to the plist. This isn't a modular way of doing such saves and can become problematic if you have a lot of information that is changing and needs to be saved all the time.  On the up side - setting up a plist save / read write structure is very easy and fast.

NSUserDefaults should be used for just that. Saving user settings and preferences. It is really easy to use NSUserDefaults, but may become very problematic in the long run if you data is very large. Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable too. This may or may not be a problem for your needs.

CoreData may be overkill for what you're doing, unless your sequence numbers are very large. Personally, I would go with CoreData knowing how it can handle dynamic values and how fast it is to save objects compared to the plist and NSUserDefaults. The down side is CoreData is a bit of a learning curve. Unless you have used it before, it is easy to go down the wrong path using it.

As far as pointers on which storage option to use, do some research. Make a list of pros and cons of each storage option. Ask yourself how big your data may get, and what is the best solution. You already know the data is dynamic and may change a lot. Look at the performance of each storage solution.

Here are some helpful reading material links straight from Apple:

[Plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD)

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

[CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)

Comment: Thanks.  If I execute multiple fetch requests, without any saves in between, will fetch requests after 1st one be executed from the memory instead of going back to the core data store?  I will keep updating seq numbers & store periodically to make sure there is no data loss if app crashes or is terminated.  With plist approach, I was thinking of storing the seq numbers in array, manipulating array to add/remove things and store it back periodically.  With COreData I can do the same, or I can just do fetch to get sequence number array each time assuming subsequent fetches are coming from memory

Comment: You may do the same with CoreData as you plan on with your plist approach. CoreData does not have saving an array as a default option, rather you would want to set an attribute with the type transient in your entity. Why not just create an entity that has an attribute that holds your seq numbers. Every time a new number comes in from your service, save it. If it changes, fetch it, update it and save it back?